# Ayuda con autocomplete jquery

Tags: jquery

Estoy haciendo una busqueda que se autocomplete usando el easy-autocomplete, todo bien, ahora el cliente vio esto.. https://www.sacatucita.com/ vean como al hacer click muestra las especialidades y al empezar a tipear comienza a buscar, ea forma de tener 2 busquedas a la vez, con click y otra con el llenado del input me tiene loco.. alguien sabe como se podria hacer?

con esto estaba autocompletando
http://easyautocomplete.com/

Comment: yo uso esto para busquedas dinamicas, espero te sirva https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/examples/

Comment: Voy a revisar eso a ver, no pierdo nada con probar

Comment: Saludos la libreria que usan en dicha pagina es "typeahead JS" para mayor detalle te sugiero revisar: https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/

Comment: Reviando, gracias a voy a ver

Comment: Revisa esto:  [select2](https://select2.github.io/select2-bootstrap-theme/4.0.3.html)

Comment: Gracias @DiegoAvila me sirvio un mundo! ese era, no se como colocarte de pregunta correcta! responde para colocarte jaja muchas gracias

Comment: te posteare un ejemplo de uso de dicha libreria..!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Saludos la libreria que buscar se llama **typeahead** un ejemplo de uso será:

```
<script src="https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/releases/latest/typeahead.bundle.js"></script>
<div id="the-basics">
  <input class="typeahead" type="text" placeholder="States of USA">
</div>
```

bien ahora debemos invocar dicha libreria:

```
var substringMatcher = function(strs) {
  return function findMatches(q, cb) {
    var matches, substringRegex;

    // an array that will be populated with substring matches
    matches = [];

    // regex used to determine if a string contains the substring `q`
    substrRegex = new RegExp(q, 'i');

    // iterate through the pool of strings and for any string that
    // contains the substring `q`, add it to the `matches` array
    $.each(strs, function(i, str) {
      if (substrRegex.test(str)) {
        matches.push(str);
      }
    });

    cb(matches);
  };
};

var states = ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas', 'California',
  'Colorado', 'Connecticut', 'Delaware', 'Florida', 'Georgia', 'Hawaii',
  'Idaho', 'Illinois', 'Indiana', 'Iowa', 'Kansas', 'Kentucky', 'Louisiana',
  'Maine', 'Maryland', 'Massachusetts', 'Michigan', 'Minnesota',
  'Mississippi', 'Missouri', 'Montana', 'Nebraska', 'Nevada', 'New Hampshire',
  'New Jersey', 'New Mexico', 'New York', 'North Carolina', 'North Dakota',
  'Ohio', 'Oklahoma', 'Oregon', 'Pennsylvania', 'Rhode Island',
  'South Carolina', 'South Dakota', 'Tennessee', 'Texas', 'Utah', 'Vermont',
  'Virginia', 'Washington', 'West Virginia', 'Wisconsin', 'Wyoming'
];

$('#the-basics .typeahead').typeahead({
  hint: true,
  highlight: true,
  minLength: 1
},
{
  name: 'states',
  source: substringMatcher(states)
});
```

espero te sirva..!!

Comment: Eres el mejor! Gracias amigo